# Finding the limit of $\frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_{2n}}{\sigma\sqrt{2n}}$ using the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

**Background Knowledge**:

> **Central Limit Theorem**:
> Assume that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. >Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}(\frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma})$ is the standard normal  distribution (where $\bar{X}_n$ is the sample mean). (taken from Wikipedia)

---

**Question**:

> Assume that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d random variables having mean
> $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Define:
>
> $$S_n:=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$$
> $$Y_n:=\frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_{2n}}{\sigma\sqrt{2n}}$$
>
> Using the central limit theorem, find the value of
> $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n$.

**My try**:

Applying the central limit theorem, we have:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}(\frac{\bar{X}_n}{\sigma})$ is the normal distribution. I do not get it. How should I reach for calculating the actual limit in the question?!

Finding the limit of $\frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_{2n}}{\sigma\sqrt{2n}}$ using the central limit theorem

Comment: Hint: In the limit you're substracting to RVs with normal distribution. Are they independent? What does that imply for your conclusion.

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera Sorry but I'm new to probability theory ... I don't get what you're implying. Would you please elaborate on it? (Maybe as an answer?)

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320265/prove-that-s-n-sqrtn-s-4n-sqrt4n-overset-w-longrightarrow-mathcaln

Comment: @GabrielRomon Is the answer the same as the question you mentioned? I am a little bit confused ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $$ \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}- \frac{S_{2n}}{\sigma\sqrt{2n}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} X_i + \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$ Let $$Y_n:=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}X_i$$ and $$Z_n:=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$ These are independent and converge in distribution to standard normal by the CLT. So what does $$ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} Y_n + \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) Z_n$$ converge in distribution to?

Comment: Is the final answer just $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ ?

Comment: @AshtonMath No. (In fact, it doesn't even depend on $\sigma$.)

Comment: So what is it? I am confused...

Comment: @AshtonMath Whatever the distribution of $(1-1/\sqrt{2})Z -Y/\sqrt{2}$ is for $Y$ and $Z$ independent N(0,1)'s. Normal with mean zero and a variance that I'm not going to calculate for you.

Comment: Oh now I get it! Thanks a lot!