# Convergence in distribution of $S_n/\sqrt{n} - S_{2n}/\sqrt{2n}$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...$ are i.i.d with $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Denote $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$. I am trying to determine if the sequence of random variables defined as:
$$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$$
converges in distribution and if so, what is the limiting distribution. Here is my thinking so far of which I tend to be doubtful. Rewriting the above I get:
$$\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{2n}}-\frac{X_{n+1}+...+X_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}=$$
$$\frac{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(X_1+...+X_n)}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(X_{n+1}+...+X_{2n})}{\sqrt{n}}$$

If I start taking large $n$, then by the central limit theorem the distributions of both rv's $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{X_{n+1}+...+X_{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ will be closer and closer to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Furthermore, for any fixed $n$ they are independent rv's. So for large $n$, I am effectively dealing with a linear combination of two independent $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ rv's. Hence, I get
$$\frac{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(X_1+...+X_n)}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(X_{n+1}+...+X_{2n})}{\sqrt{n}}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2)$$
and consequently:
$$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2) $$

I am aware that this is not a rigorous proof, but is my intuition correct or is it misleading me completely? Will highly appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Your intuition is correct; see this question for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108590

Comment: Thank you @charmd! I somehow missed the other question.

Comment: Do you mean to assume that the random variables are not only i.i.d. but also all standard normal? If this is the case, there is no need for the CLT, as the normal distribution is closed under linear transformations, and the final distribution is exact for all $n$.